# Javadoc access with Checkstyle?

Tags: javadoc, checkstyle

Is there a way in the Checkstyle API to access the text of a javadoc comment?
How?

"I still haven't found what I'm looking for"

Comment: Checkstyle project is considering to add support for Comments validation , please support  proposals at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkstyle/VEVFDsZKLzg

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle provides an API that does expose comments. The method [FileContents.getJavadocBefore](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FileContents.html#getJavadocBefore%28int%29) can be used to locate the Javadoc before a certain location in a file.

Have a look at the source code for the Checkstyle checks that process Javadoc - see [here](http://checkstyle.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/checkstyle/checkstyle/file/431cd7fef670/src/checkstyle/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc). A good example is [JavadocStyleCheck](http://checkstyle.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/checkstyle/checkstyle/file/431cd7fef670/src/checkstyle/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/JavadocStyleCheck.java).

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you Oliver.  How about nonJavaDoc comments?  My stupid company requires specific comment header blocks at the top of a file, prior to class definitions, and methods.  I'm using the Regexp in the config file to validate the file header comments.  But, if there is a nonJavaDoc comment before a class or method, can I access the text?   My clunky solution is to get a CTOR_DEF or METHOD_DEF, then get the line number...then get the filecontents...find the line, then try to backup to the comment header.  Please help...thanks.